# Set global value for static of ViewChild

Tags: angular9

In angular 9 static value of ViewChild has a default value (false). Can I change the default value? Globally for my application

Comment: Pass your value - Will change the default one

Comment: That's not possible and why would you want the default to be `true`? This will cause quite some issues if you have structural directives around your viewChild

Comment: ```@ViewChild('something', { static: true }) something: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;``` ?

Answer (score 0):

**static: true** has to be used when you want to access the ViewChild in ngOnInit.

**static: false** has to be used when you want to access the ViewChild in ngAfterViewInit. When you have a structural directive (*ngIf) on your template.